# Convert type of anonymous object in linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following situation, I have a function which returns a `List<object`, because the object can be 2 different types `Class1` or `Class2`, but never mixed. I use this List for a lot of things, but at some point I need a list with names of the objects: `List<string>`.

I know how to do this in a for loop, but I would like to know if there is a neat linq/lambda trick for this. Since it simplifies the code.

```
// An extreme simplified version of my code
List<object> result = this.ProcesInput(input, useFullProces);
List<string> resultNames;

// The following ideas didn't work.
if (useFullProces)
{
    resultNames = result.Select(x as Class2 => x.ID.toString()).ToList();
    resultNames = result.Select(x => (Class2)x.ID.toString()).ToList();
}
else
{
    resultNames = result.Select(x as Class1 => x.name).ToList();
}
```

Also I know this can be considered dangerous code, but in my situation the type of the returned object is defined by the `useFullProces` boolean and will therefore work.

Comment: Rather than "it didn't work", what *happened* in your attempts? The "x as Class1" isn't syntactically valid, and `toString()` is unlikely to be the method name you want, but you should always state your errors... and ideally produce a short but *complete* example.

Comment: How about result.Select(x => new Class2() { SomeProp = x.Something }

Comment: Returning a 'List<object>' if a bad idea. I recommend you to create an interface which forces both clases to implement a method to get the string id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you just want:

```
List<string> names = useFullProcess
    ? result.Cast<Class2>().Select(x => x.ID.ToString()).ToList()
    : result.Cast<Class1>().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

You *can* use a cast within your `Select`, but it's not as clear IMO:

```
List<string> names = useFullProcess
    ? result.Select(x => ((Class2) x).ID.ToString()).ToList()
    : result.Select(x => ((Class1) x).Name).ToList();
```

Comment: The second works, the first wont compile because ID and name are unrecognized properties of obejct x

Comment: @kpp: The first definitely *should* work, now that I've fixed the typo. `x` won't be of type `object` after the `Cast` call.

Comment: OfType<> instead of Cast<> would be a bit 'safer'.

Comment: @Fratyx: Nope. Cast will fail if something went wrong (which is a good thing, since it alerts the developer that there is a bug). OfType will just silently ignore the "wrong" entries, leading to hard-to-find bugs later on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the correct object:

```
resultNames = result.Select(x => ((Class2)x).ID.toString()).ToList();
```

or:

```
resultNames = result.Select(x => (x as Class2).ID.toString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: As I see there are already two answer which uses cast, so I am going to propose you another solution.That doesn't mean you have to implement it or not.

If you know you're going to have only `Class1` and `Class2` as types and each one is available on different `if-else branch`  you can take advantage of `DLR` ( dynamic language runtime ).

Let's say you have the 2 `classes` you mentioned above.

```
public class Class1
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

You said you know on each branch what types you. So on `if` branch let's say you have a list formed by `Class2` type objects and on `else` branch you have a list with `Class1` objects.

```
List<dynamic> result = this.ProcesInput(input, useFullProces);
List<string> resultNames;
```

At this point you have a list of dynamic objects formed by `Class1` or `Class2` objects, but never mixed. So both cast and using dynamic should work. You won't get a cast exception because you have objects of same type in your list and also you won't get `RuntimeBindingException` when requesting for a property that doesn't exist on that item from the list, because you know what to ask for ( as you said in your question ).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if (useFullProces)
{
    resultNames= result.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();  
}
else
{
    resultNames = result.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
}
```

**Note** : If your list is mixed with `Class1` and `Class2` objects you'll get a runtime exception when requesting for a field that doesn't exists.

**Not another note** : Note I made above is also available for cast. You'll get `System.InvalidCastException` exception.

You won't have `intellisense` because your type is evaluated by DLR at execution time and not at the compile time. Also you don't need to make other casts, boxing or unboxings in your code.

PS: `DLR` is available from C# 4.0

Comment: Look at the code being used in this case - they don't both have the same properties. In one case the OP is calling `x.Id.ToString()`, and in the other case they're using `x.Name`.

Comment: He said this "in my situation the type of the returned object is defined by the `useFullProces` boolean", so he knows what type to expect on each branch. I also proposed this solution because there were already 2 answers which uses `cast`.   In both cases you get an exception if something wrong happened ( cast didn't work or a binder exception if property doesn't exists ).  Of course, please tell me if I got this wrong. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, he knows what to expect on each branch - but they're shaped differently, so you can't use dynamic typing to get to some "common" property... there isn't one. Maybe you're thinking of something different - it doesn't help that your sample code basically doesn't match the model in the question...

Comment: I've updated my answer with better explanations. What do you mean by shaped differently ? For example `Class1` will always be `Class1`, it will always have same properties ( hope I assumed this correctly ). Even if you use cast or dynamic, if `result` list is mixed with both `Class1` and `Class2` objects, an exception will be fired.

Comment: Now you've updated your answer, I see what you mean - you've still got the `if`. I thought you were trying to get rid of that by using `dynamic` to access the same named property from different classes. I don't see that using dynamic here is better than `Cast` - in fact, I'd say it's worse, in that it could happen to work in cases where you don't really want it to (if your result has a `Class3` for some unexpected reason, but it happens to have the expected property).

Comment: Yeah! I realised my written answer was different from the one I had in my mind :). I get your point now. Thanks! In that case is better to `cast`.